# Robot_Localization Local/Global ekf nodes

Tags: ros2, robot-localization, gps, ekf, ekf-localization

I have a doubt regarding the use of Robot_localization.

I was watching this tutorial: https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_with_gps.html

in my case I have a real robot (equipped with imu, gps, and wheel encoders) with which I already publish a transformation between the base_link frame of my robot and the odom frame.

I've seen that the many examples around (like the tutorial above) use 2 ekf nodes, the first to compute the local odom--base_link transformation, and a second to compute the global map-odom transformation.

But if I already have the odom--base_link transformation existing and therefore the odom frame already exists, is it always necessary for me to create the two ekf nodes?

or can I just create the global node ekf?

Thanks everyone in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a node already does the transform between base_link to odom, then you do not need to have two instances of robot_localization. You just configure one instance of EKF to provide the transform between map and odom.